# Terminal command to delete everything I've ever created

Tags: terminal, search, macos

I have so much junk installed on my work laptop I want to start with a fresh machine. However, I must keep the account I have as I do not have system permissions to create another account. How can I use terminal to delete everything I (including use of git, brew, port, svn, etc) ever made?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to neccesarily delete everything. Deleting everything would give you a hard time getting the computer to start or installing the OS. With Terminal, I suppose that `sudo rm -rf /` would delete everything.

If you want to start fresh, you can boot into Recovery <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. **Use only the <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd> key if you don't have FileVault installed because it has a root console**.

And then reinstall OS. Also, if you don't have permissions, I mentioned the root console. I am not exactly sure if Internet Recovery also has the console.

Comment: hat would the potential consequences be of using  `rm -rf /` without the `sudo` command?

Comment: It would simply show "Permission Denied". There is a sudo console on Recovery. However, it is **NOT** recommended to do so. You would have a hard time getting the computer to work or installing OS. You should rather go to Recovery and reinstall OS. Or go to the root console and `rm -rf /Users/username/*` This will erase an entire user